# passing ng-repeat object back to controller function without event (draw canvas)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

scope.threads contains specific information for each thread on how the canvas script should work. i need the canvas to execute the function on the correct canvas by inputting the variables from that thread (in threads) into the function... if that some sense

html top layer:

```
<div ng-repeat="thread in threads">
    <mx-thread-preview></mx-thread-preview>
</div>
```

mx-thread-preview directive template [function uses that id]:

```
<canvas id="{{thread.OPID}}" ng-model="huh" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid red;">
</canvas>
```

mx-thread-preview function inside directive. takes the thread (in threads) object and gets the thread.OPID to grab the canvas element, then will use thread.image.linewidth to input linewidth, and the other parts of the drawing process...etc.

if there is a better way to do this I'd like to know

```
scope.generateImage(????);

generateImage = function(obj){
var c = document.getElementById(obj.OPID);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.lineWidth=obj.image.linewidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle=obj.image.color;
    ctx.moveTo(0,3);
    ctx.lineTo(50,30);
    ctx.moveTo(10,50);
    ctx.stroke();
    console.log('the OPID of image is')
}
```

the thread-preview directive in which the canvas resides:

```
angular.module('threadPreview',[])

.directive('mxThreadPreview', ['testData', 'threadData', 'imageBotData', function(testData, threadData, imageBotData){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'catalog/threadPreview/thread-preview.html',
  scope: true,
  transclude: true,
  link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.threads = threadData.threads;
    scope.generateImage = imageBotData.generateImage
    scope.generateImage(thread);
  }
 }}])
```

Comment: can you place your minimal `directive` code? Basically, you can try the `thread` to be assigned to directive `ng-model="thread"` and can access the same inside the thread.

Comment: I added the thread-preview directive I used. I tried the ng-model="thread" inside of the template and then passing that back in thread-preview as scope.generateImage(thread) and got this error........................... thread is not defined
    at Object.link (http://localhost:8080/app/catalog/threadPreview/thread-preview.js:12:25)

Comment: it works when I do not pass thread/anything else passing in un-specific information, not with angular though.